# Run 3 bash scripts simultaneously then send their return values as JSON in REST API NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, bash, event-loop

I'm trying to run 3 bash scripts depending on what the JSON list sent from the client specifies, then return their outputs to a JSON dict which will be sent to the client again.

This is the code of the three scripts:

```
marc@linux:~ $ cat 1.sh
sleep 1
echo -n "a"
marc@linux:~ $ cat 2.sh
sleep 1
echo -n "b"
marc@linux:~ $ cat 3.sh
sleep 1
echo -n "c"
```

If I executed them synchronously, they might stop the event loop for 3 seconds (undesirable):

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json())

const cp = require("child_process");


app.get("/", (request, response) => {
    console.log(request.body);

    var response_data = {};
    if (request.body.includes("script1")) {
        response_data.value1 = cp.execFileSync("./1.sh").toString();
    }
    if (request.body.includes("script2")) {
        response_data.value2 = cp.execFileSync("./2.sh").toString();
    }
    if (request.body.includes("script3")) {
        response_data.value3 = cp.execFileSync("./3.sh").toString();
    }


    response.json(response_data);
    response.status(200)
    response.send()
})

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("ready");
})
```

And if I executed them asynchronously, they would return after the response is sent, where the response would be just `{}`

My intended flow chart is that if I send `["script1", "script3"]`, it should return `{"value1": "a", "value3": "c"}` when the `1.sh` and `3.sh` are done executing, and without blocking the event loop.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJbdy.png)

How do I implement callbacks/promises in such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Use Promise.all() for that:

```js
const run = (script) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // spawns cp for script
    // without any args and options
    cp.execFile(`./${script.slice(-1)}.sh`, null, null, (res, err) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        // returns res through callback
        resolve(res);
    });
});

const runScripts = (req) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const 
        result = {},
        promises = [];

    // creates promise for each script in request
    for (script of req) {
        // pushes it to the required array of promises for Promise.all
        promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // runs script 
            run(script).then((res) => {
                // gets scripts result
                // and writes it
                result[`value${script.slice(-1)}`] = res;
                resolve();
            });
        }));
    };

    // uses Promise.all to wait until all scripts are done
    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        // when each script is done
        // finally returns final result
        resolve(result);
    });
});

// put req as your request.body
runScripts(req).then((res) => {
    // sends final result as response
    response.status(200).json(result);
}).catch((err) => {
    // if something goes wrong
    response.status(500).json('Something broke!');
});
```

I couldn't check this code because because I have Windows.
If I try to execute scripts with child_process, it's tells me that I'm trying to execute UNKNOWN, even if I used sync function in test without anything, just `console.log(cp.execFileSync("./1.sh").toString());`. But, it worked for you.

So try it and tell me if it works or not.

P.S. Edited for error handling.